# XML File as database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to use single XML file for Ruby on Rails as an ActiveRecord database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, AFAIK,

I would suggest you to use sqlite3 as database, since it's lightweight and small. If you want to generate XML from that, you can just use `to_xml` method :)

Comment: Yes, I think that't the way I'll use, because there are no working XML adapters for ActiveRecord over the net :(

Comment: Why is this an answer?  Everything is possible, or is rails all of the sudden not Turing complete? You just don't know how.  Now I have to go find out how to actually do it.

Answer (score 3):

Read [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201568/when-would-i-use-xml-instead-of-sql) for a rundown on this topic.  The answer boils down to scalability and data integrity.  At some point the data file will get big enough that it will need on-disk indexes, which are not directly supported in XML.  Also, an XML file is not transactional - it has no logs.  To implement a transactional storage in an XML file you would have to implement a DBMS, and create supplemental transactional log and index files.  This is almost certainly far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks.. now this should be the answer.. yeah it's hard, and it shouldn't be done for anything lasting. But it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it *was* possible, but you **really** wouldn't want to do it!

It would involve writing a new XML ActiveRecord adapter that would issue XPath (presumably) queries against your file where the other adapters would generate SQL. I suppose you'd also need migrations to maintain XSD or DTD files.

It's horrible. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/xml_active seems to do the job. I'm digging deeper, but it is where I'm starting.